# How to setup TFS 2010 to send emails whenever a build fails?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I've tried using the Alerts project of VS 2010, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get emails when the build completes successfully?  Also, are checkin email notifications working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alerts respond to failing builds. Did you check the [smtp settings on the TFS Application Tier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx)?

Did you also check whether mails can send. I am not a real infra-guy, but you could use telnet. What I do is write a simple app that sends mail via the same smtp server and when you run the app, you get the error message.

Comment: I'll try them out and give a feedback.